# Force where close on every query of a model plus nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, default-scope

I first had in mind to use the `default_scope` to force a condition on every requests but it doesn't seems to work.

For example, if I have `Product.include(:prices)` it will no use the default scope. I'm not sure if its the correct behavior.

My `default_scope` for prices is something like that:

```
default_scope where(type: "normal")
```

I'm working on a "crm" ported to rails and the only type of price that interest us is the "normal" one. I could edit the code everywhere but it would be much simpler to "enforce" a condition whenever the price needs to be queried from the database. And for that same reason, using `named_scope` isn't an alternative either for now since it might require a lot of refactor.

Some more information as it "should" work but doesn't...

```
class Ts::Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_terrasoft
  default_scope where(PriceKindID: "{43D5117A-D52D-4E72-B33B-7D3158524BF1}")

  .. 

  other scopes

  ..
end
```

The actual call

```
products = Product.includes(:supplier, :prices, :user)

... some more where unrelated to prices

products = products.find(:all, {
  conditions: {
      :vendors_Products => {
          AccountTypeID: type
      }
  },
  limit: @count,
  offset: @offset * @count
})
```

The Products

```
class Ts::Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_terrasoft

  self.table_name =   "Products"
  self.primary_key =  "ID"

  has_many :prices, class_name: "::Ts::Price", foreign_key: "ProductID", :dependent => :destroy
end
```

## Edit

Rails 3.2.8

Comment: That is unusual - I've just tested this and found that when I use `.includes`, the included models *do* use their `default_scope`. Perhaps you could include some additional details - your Rails version, and perhaps the query that is executed when you call `Product.includes(:prices)`?